# Is there a way to make a qnabot search an online sharepoint database if there is no answer found in the qna database?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, botframework, bots, azure-qna-maker

I am in the process of creating a QnA bot for Microsoft Teams. I am using the QnA maker to create my knowledge base and coding the bot with Visual Studios 2019. I am curious as to whether it is possible to make the bot search a separate SharePoint database if an answer is not found in the QnA knowledge base. (I am not very well versed in coding in general, sorry!)

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. If you can take a look at the [sample here](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker/Bots/QnABot.cs), you will notice that [this line](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/0e26fd886d2e4ef39070c44d496563df5f158645/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/11.qnamaker/Bots/QnABot.cs#L51) handles the case where no QnA answers were found. You could replace this line, with code to call SharePoint and return whatever you needed from it. Or probably best, make your call to SharePoint and if no results ***there***, then then just return a friendly message ("No answers were found.")

Additionally, you can look at the [score](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/concepts/confidence-score) of the answer, and [determine if](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-publish-answer#get-an-answer) you need to continue to SharePoint or not.